# Use DD to write specific file recursively

Tags: linux, drive, hard-drive, dd, computer-forensics

I have a hard drive that I want to overwrite, not with null bytes, but with a message.

48 69 64 64 65 6e 20 = "Hidden "

Here's my command thus far:

```
echo "Hidden " > /myfile
dd if=/myfile of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Note: I have also tried an assorment of parameters such as count and conv to no avail

Now, this is fine. When I run:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | hexdump -C | less
```

I can see the first few bytes written over, however, the rest is unchanged. I'd like to recursively write "Hidden " to the drive.

Comment: You meant `repeatedly`, not `recursively`. See [recursion on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Your question has been already answered and accepted, but here's a helpful hint for saving you some typing:

    `dd if=/dev/sdb | hexdump -C | less`

Can be written as:

    `hexdump -C /dev/sdb | less`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have a spare disk to try this out on, but you can use the [`yes` command to continuously push your string into the pipe](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=yes%20%22Hidden%22%20%7C%20paste%20-d%27%20%27%20-s%20-%20%7C%20dd%20of=/dev/sdb):

```
yes "Hidden" | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

I assume once dd has written the whole disk, then it will close the pipe and this command will finish.

The above will newline-delimit the "Hidden" string.  If you want it space-delimited, as in the question you can do:

```
yes "Hidden" | paste -d' ' -s - | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

Or if you want it null-delimited:

```
yes "Hidden" | tr '\n' '\0' | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: This one did it! Thanks!
The paste command isn't required, but it's a lot neater in there with a null delimiter.

Comment: +1 from me too, learn something every day, never heard of the `yes` command  :)

Comment: Yes, the `paste` command isn't strictly necessary unless you want "Hidden" to be space-delimited.  Otherwise it will be newline-delimited.  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify `if` parameter, input is read from stdin. This allows you to do something like this:

```
dd of=/dev/sdb < for((i=0;i<100000;i++)); do echo 'Hidden '; done;
```

The value of `100000` obviously needs to be at least `diskSizeInBytes / strlen('Hidden ')`.

Given the consequences I didn't test this for you but it ought to work  ;)

Comment: Hmmm... it didn't seem to take the parenthesis, so building off of your idea I made this:

`for((i=0;i<100000;i++)); do echo 'Hidden ' | dd of=/dev/sdb; done;`

which seems to simply write "Hidden " 100000 times in the first bytes :)

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way round - you're now starting `dd` 100000 times instead of piping the combined output of 100000 echos to it once. Move the entire `dd` call out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

[dcfldd](http://dcfldd.sourceforge.net/), a fork of dd, has some additional features that you may find useful. For example, your problem would be solved by:

```
dcfldd textpattern="Hidden " of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```